# How to store more than one image reference in a database field

Tags: php, html, sql, image

I'm developing a website whereby users search for properties based on certain filters and results are shown in a table. One of the fields in the table is an image for the property. However I want to store multiple images for the property which can be viewed when it's clicked on.

At the moment I store a reference to a filename which I use to interact with a fileserver online and have one image field in my database where I store this reference. How do I go about storing more than one image per property and displaying certain ones when I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a separated DB table for images with foreign key being your property primary key.
Another way, not recommended, is to store all file names inside one field in your property table, separating them i.e. by comma or colon etc.